# Monstera root coming out of pot hole after being sick

Tags: houseplants, plant-care, roots, monstera

edit: I've only touched the root and it seems to be already a bit rotten, so I just pulled it out, hope for good!

So I have this *Monstera* plant that after some time of not growing I took out of it's pot to discover root rot, removed all the rotten roots and managed to get some healthy in a new pot and soil and it did managed to grow a new leaf and recover! Amazing recovery but now I have this ceramic pot with one hole at the bottom which drain pretty well but there's one root that comes out of it which I don't really know what to do about, what do you think? Pictures added.

|  | pot | plant |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [image: this is the root coming out] | [image: the pot] | [image: the whole plant] |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just cut it - the plant will learn that's not where roots should go and it'll stop.

Comment: I'm kind of afraid that's the.plant's biggest if not only healthy root... By cut it you mean from outside ?

Comment: @zoroakalior Yes, from the outside.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned, you could just cut it but while it is still short I usually try to guide it back inside the pot.

Other option is that you could just leave it, although it has a higher risk of rotting and that could spread inside. If there is enough room and air under the pot it could be fine though.

Comment: The plant looks small enough that OP could probably (gently) pull it out of the pot and guide the root to a better location while reinserting.

Comment: @mcalex Yes that is a feasible option as well. While it is OK to cut roots, I like to leave it as a last resort. :D

Comment: thank you, I've edited the question now with the result.. it kind of cut off by itself when I touched it, although looking really healthy two days ago maybe the time outside with not so much air there to grow, will see how it goes! thanks!